# Help sculpting Malwiya mosque

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I need help to sculpt the Mawiya mosque depicted below:

[image].

I tried to do that in Blender 2.81 but I couldn't bring the same spiral walking path. That is what I came out with:

[image]

I have used Cylinders to preform that but I was stuck with creating the walking path from the ground to the top of the mosque! I imagine that should be easy for an expert to do in Blender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can probably achieve what you're looking for using (mostly) the Screw modifier. Here are 3 approaches...

***Method 1: Screw + Proportional Editing***

I forgot to make sure the walking paths aren't partially above one another on the Z-axis in this approach, but I think it can be adjusted to get that right:

Start with a simple plane:

[image]

Apply a Screw modifier:

[image]

Then we'll apply the Screw modifier to the mesh, and get ready to use proportional editing to adjust the mesh's shape:

[image]

Next we'll actually do the proportional editing. Note that I'm doing this with Shift+Z (to only edit the width & length, not the height, of the structure), that my proportional editing circle-of-influence is quite large, and that I've set the Pivot Point to my 3D cursor (which is set to a position in the center of the structure's X-Y plane):

[image]

This process leaves an open hole in the center of the structure, so I then added a single cylinder to fill it in. I think you'll probably need a separate cylinder for each layer, but the same basic idea should work:

[image]

***Method 2: SimpleDeform + Screw + SimpleDeform***

We start with a plane in the same setup as in Step 0 above (not shown here). We can then add the 3 modifiers in the title of this method, with setting as given below, and get a reasonable facsimile to the Malwiya mosque's structure:

[image]

You may then want to apply modifiers and edit this, but it seems like a good starting point for the desired structure. To give a little bit of intuition for why this particular modifier stack seems to work: I started by observing that the Malwiya mosque looks like, well, a screw, except that its walkway's radius tapers off as you approach its summit. Simple deform gives us the option to taper (either before or after the Screw, or both, as we did here), and so playing with a few combinations of these two modifiers seemed natural.

***Method 3: Archemedian Spiral with Extrusion***

I couldn't quite stop playing with options, so here's a third one: you should be able to pretty easily generate the desired shape using a curve to model the desired spiral, adding Bevel & Taper objects to get the desired walkway shape/height, and finally filling in any gaps with cylinders or other objects as appropriate.

In particular, there is a very nice "Archemedian Spiral" object available for free (though I believe you have to turn on the "extra objects" add-on to see it):

[image]

If we add a Bezier curve with 3 points as the Archemedian spiral's Bevel object, then we can play with it a bit to get a nice basis for the kind of spiral walkway that wraps around Malwiya mosque:

[image]

You would then probably want to rotate this a bit to get the walkway to angle in the same fashion as in your image, and convert it to a mesh and extrude the geometry to fill in empty space.

Answer (score 5):

You could use two of the shipped add-ons help you make the basic structure in a few steps:

- Activate the add-ons 'Add Curve: Extra Objects' and 'F2'.
- Set your snap to 'Vertex' and 'Active'
- Create a Curve > Curve Spirals > Archimedean, and adjust the settings to the outside profile of your tower
- Header > Object menu > Convert the curve to a mesh
- In Edit Vertex mode, with all selected and a  convenient vertex active, <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> extrude the walls upwards, snapping the active vertex in Z to the one above it
- In Edge Mode, select the opposite sides of the bottom section of the pathway and hit <kbd>F</kbd>
- Select the upward edge of the new face, and hold <kbd>F</kbd> down until the pathway is filled.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Robin your method worked for me so far http://prntscr.com/ptzz5h however I couldn't add a subdivision surface to enhance the smoothness of the Malwiya as when I add it the whole building gets distorted!  http://prntscr.com/ptzz5h why is that?

Comment: Hi @Robin, sorry for that ;-) http://prntscr.com/pu51zz. hmmm, would the loop cuts fix that issue? I will give it a try

Comment: Ok @Robin, I have tried that also and it didn't help that much.

Comment: Hi @Robin, Actually the loop cuts with the shade smooth made the trick,  but without adding the subdivision surface. check it here:  http://prntscr.com/pu5lii

Comment: @Omar it'll be  a question of your topology, so wireframe would need to be visible, Yes, loop cuts/bevels.. and have a look for duplicate vertices in there (select all, alt-M, merge by distance)